# Why does `print hashlib.sha224(some_string).digest()` differs from its `repr()`?

Tags: python, mysql, hash, repr

I want to store some hashes of some strings in my Database table. For that I created a column of type varchar(64). I do generate the hashes like this:

```
>>> thehash = hashlib.sha224(some_string).digest()
```

Now I realize that

```
>>> print thehash
```

is not the same as

```
>>> thehash
```

(By now, I know the difference between `>>> print 'test'` and `>>> 'test'`... :-)) I am confused which part I should store now. The `repr()` or the other version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither. You should call the `.hexdigest()` method instead and store that.

Comment: If I may ask: What is the difference between `diggest()` and `hexdiggest`? And why should I store the latter?

Comment: `.digest()` returns the hash as binary data, whereas `.hexdigest()` returns the hash encoded as hexadecimal digits. You want the latter since it will practically always be printable, transportable, and consistent.